# Why is my custom font not displayed (HTML, CSS, BEGINNER)

Tags: html, css

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>innomotion media</title>
  <style type="text/css" media="screen, print">
    @font-face {
      font-family: "Baiti";
      src: url(fonts/baiti.ttf");
    }

    body { font-family: "Baiti", serif }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  This is Baiti
</body>
</html>
```

As a long time coder, I have always dodged HTML or CSS. But it is time I need a webpage. Basic syntax is clear to me, however I already stumbled across using my custom font.

The html file is located on my drive. Next to it is a local folder called "fonts". I thought I had referenced that folder correctly and by opening the webpage, the font "Baiti" is used.

But it isnt. It displayed some def. times new roman or something.

What is it I am doing wrong?

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>innomotion media</title>
  <style type="text/css" media="screen, print">
    @font-face {
      font-family: "Baiti";
      src: url(fonts/baiti.ttf");
    }

    body { font-family: "Baiti", serif }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  This is Baiti
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are missing an opening quotation in your `@font-face`. It should be `src: url("fonts/baiti.ttf");`

Comment: **url(fonts/baiti.ttf");** has one quotation symbol in it. try using it as like *url("fonts/baiti.ttf");* and also check font path is correct. also note that you should use WOFF or WOFF2 font types, they have better support in browsers

Comment: geezus. well, I think I need to ask you: what is the best interface to code html in? I use notepad++ but this is just an easy syntax error... What program would display those to me? Thank you!

Comment: It would be much better if you generate fonts-webkit and then use `woff` or `woff2` as they are used for webs you can generate on the website of fontsquirrel. https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
src: url("./fonts/baiti.ttf");
```

Also make sure that the Font Family matches the name when you preview the font. and also the type if you are using `woff` or `woff2`

like,

```
src: url("./fonts/baiti.woff");
src: url("./fonts/baiti.woff2");
```